# String resources are not translated at runtime for API 21 - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, locale, android-resources

So I wanted to test my app on a lower API level and I stumbled across a weird problem with the string resources translations.

I have 2 emulators - One runs API 26 and the other API 21.

On the API level 26 phone everything translates fine when the application is set to a different language than english, but on the API level 21 phone the app just wont translate, the language stays english.. which is weird because its clearly working on my regular emulator (and also real device).

If any of you know a solution for this problem please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What languages does your app support? And what language are you trying in? Newer versions of android will choose languages that are "close" (e.g., different regions of the same language family) whereas older versions require an exact match.

Comment: Curretly the app contains only english and hebrew. When i'm trying to change to hebrew the API 21 phone is not translating at all. When i added hebrew it created a new directory called "values-iw-rIL" which is also the only language code for hebrew as far as i know. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so I guess i solved it because of something you said, i removed the -rIL and now it works